# Unable to underline text in Flask project using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am working on a Flask project where I need to underline specific text in the user input based on the response received from the server. I am using Flask for the backend and JavaScript for the frontend.

Here's my Flask code:

```
@app.route('/text', methods=['POST'])
def text():
    user_text = request.form['user_input']

    payload = {
        "providers": "cohere",
        "language": "en",
        "text": user_text,
        "fallback_providers": "",
    }

    response = requests.post(url2, json=payload, headers=headers)

    result = json.loads(response.text)
    res = result['cohere']['items']
    return jsonify(text=res)
```

This is my js code

```
fetch('/text', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        let text = data.text;
        console.log("Extracted Text:", text);

        text.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.type === "error") {
                let regex = new RegExp(`\\b${item.text}\\b`, "g");
                userInputInput.innerHTML = userInputInput.innerHTML.replace(regex, `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">${item.text}</span>`);
            }
        });

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching response:", error);
    });
```

In the JavaScript code, I am trying to underline specific text in the user input based on the server response. While I can see the result in the console log, the text is not getting underlined as expected.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the text is not getting underlined as expected.

Comment: What is `userInputInput`?  That's never defined in the code.  If the problem is in the client-side code, specifically the part where you use `userInputInput`, please update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates this problem.

Comment: const userInputInput = document.getElementById("user-input");
it is a textarea that i created in the html

Comment: And how specifically does this fail?  If `userInputInput` is a `<textarea>` then I'd expect that it just displays the HTML code as text, and you may be looking to use a content-editable `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display other HTML elements inside a textarea. Consider using a contenteditable div element instead (with appropriate styling):

```html
<div id="userInputInput" contenteditable>Content...</div>
```